# Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='content column']

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

The following code gives me an error even though xpath is right:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='content column']...

I assume there are multiple xpaths in the field. Here is the code.

```
driver.get("https://marswebtdc.tdc.vzwcorp.com/cdl/lte/fdr_llc/fdr.jsp?3gOr4g=4g");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

try {
    int i = 5;
    String strI = Integer.toString(i);

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content column']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/form/b/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/input"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content column']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/form/b/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/input")).sendKeys(strI);

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Elemnt Not Found : "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Html snippet

```
<table align="left" width="100%" border="1"  bgColor=#ffffff borderColorDark='white' borderColorLight='gray' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>
    <table border='0' bgColor=#ffffff width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="left" nowrap>(Data available 07/30/2014 to 01/26/2015)</td>
            <td rowspan="3" valign="top" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Search"><br/>    
                <input type="reset" name="action" value=" Reset "><br/>    
                <input type="button" name="action" value=" Print " onClick="Print_onClick()"><br/>    
        <input type="button" name="action" value="Download CSV" onClick="parent.frames['results'].download_result()" disabled><br>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="top">Begin Date:</td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" name="txtBeginDate" value='01/26/2015' size="10" maxlength="10"
                       onBlur="doFormatDate(this)">
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="top">MDN:</td>
            <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="txtMsid" value="" size="15" maxlength="15"  onKeyUp="removeStuff(this)" onBlur="removeStuff(this)" onPaste="return removeStuff(this)"></td>
```

form`form`java`

```
function validate(form)
{
    var msg = "";
    var bDate = form.txtBeginDate.value;
    var eDate = form.txtEndDate.value;
    var abDate = form.abd.value;
    var aeDate = form.aed.value;
    var msid = form.txtMsid.value;

    if (!validDate(bDate))
        msg += "o  Begin Date is not a valid date.\n";
    if (!validDate(eDate))
        msg += "o  End Date is not a valid date.\n";
    if (compareDate(bDate, eDate))
        msg += "o  Begin Date must be less than or equal to End Date.\n";
    if (compareDate(abDate, bDate) || compareDate(eDate, aeDate))
        msg += "o  Date entered are out of the available date range.\n";
    if (calculateDays(bDate, eDate) > 30) 
        msg += "o  Date range cannot be more than 30 days.\n";

    if (isBlank(msid))
        msg += "o  MDN must be entered.\n";
    if (!isNumber(msid) || (msid.length > 0 && msid.length < 10))
        msg += "o  MDN must be numeric and 10 digits in length.\n";
    if (!isAllowedPhoneNumber(msid) ){
        msg += "o  MDN " + msid + " is not an allowed value.\n";
    }
    if (msg > "") {
        msg = "Problems with data entry:\n" + msg;
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (!toggleSearch(false)) {
            msg = "A search is pending! No new search may be issued until pending search returns.\n";
            alert(msg);
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
}
</script>
<!--</head><body>-->
```

```
        <td colspan="4" align="left" nowrap>(Data available 07/31/2014 to 01/27/2015)</td>
        <td rowspan="3" valign="top" align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Search"><br/>    
            <input type="reset" name="action" value=" Reset "><br/>    
            <input type="button" name="action" value=" Print " onClick="Print_onClick()"><br/>    
    <input type="button" name="action" value="Download CSV" onClick="parent.frames['results'].download_result()" disabled><br>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Begin Date:</td>
        <td valign="top">
            <input type="text" name="txtBeginDate" value='01/27/2015' size="10" maxlength="10"
                   onBlur="doFormatDate(this)">
        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="top">MDN:</td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="txtMsid" value="" size="15" maxlength="15"  onKeyUp="removeStuff(this)" onBlur="removeStuff(this)" onPaste="return removeStuff(this)"><enter code here/td>
```

Comment: Did you try css selector?

Comment: yes i did, it doesnt work

Comment: What is your css selector value? please tell

Comment: its more than one. <input type="submit" value="Search" name="action"/>
<br/>
<input type="reset" value=" Reset " name="action"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="Print_onClick()" value=" Print " name="action"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" disabled="" onclick="parent.frames['results'].download_result()" value="Download CSV" name="action"/>

Comment: you just do right click on your corresponding <input> tag and click on get css path. and use that as css selector. Do this action using chrome.

Comment: It's very confusing as you are not making it clearer.. Can you please add a screenshot of the page you are trying to automate? Since, your reputation is tad low, please [upload the screenshot in imgur](http://imgur.com/) and add the link in your question. Also if you can mark which element you want to locate (in the screenshot), that will be more helpful.. :)

Comment: here is the link. http://imgur.com/dXLFkHN. the element is td align ="right" valign="top">MDN:</td> < input type ='text' name = "txtMsid" value ="" size ="15"......

Comment: @Vzwpowertestverizon123: You've added the page source.. Please add the webpage's screenshot and mark the element you want to locate in there.

Comment: http://imgur.com/hYIHpHj

Comment: Thanks.. From what I can see, the xpaths provided in my answer should work. Can you check, if the element is inside a frame or something ?

Comment: i already tried it and still doesnt work. i'm not sure whether it is a frame or not. what happen if is a frame?  onKeyUp="removeStuff(this)" onBlur="removeStuff(this)" onPaste="return removeStuff(this)"></td>, whats this removeStuff(this) means?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use xpaths, especially such as yours. Difficult to understand, read, maintain etc. Read about [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
. If i correctly understood which element you need to find you can try next selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.Css("input#3gOr4g"));
```

or smth like this =)

Comment: Also, it's possible that your xpath is invalid and really can't locate element. Try it in browser. And better use css selectors

Comment: css still doesnt work. this is the element i need : <input type="text" name="txtMsid" value="" size="15" maxlength="15"  onKeyUp="removeStuff(this)" onBlur="removeStuff(this)" onPaste="return removeStuff(this)">

Comment: Interesting. Is it throws exception? what kind?is this element visible/exists on the page? or you need to click on smth else so that elem becomes visible/or appear on the page? P.S. i made a little type in the selector. For your element selector should be smth like ("input[name='txtMsid']")

Comment: if i select that field by using Firebug, it selects multiple fields but not just one. And i heard there can be more one xpath that is in same selectors and we need to indentify that.

Comment: You mean, there are multiple **"MDN:" textfields** ?

Comment: i mean if i select one text field, it get selected multiple fields in Firebug for css. for xpath it gives only one.

Comment: you just do right click on your corresponding <input> tag and click on get css path. and use that as css selector. Do this action using chrome.

Comment: @Vzwpowertest: What I meant was, in case there are multiple **"MDN:" textfields**, then it's possible that when you are searching for the concerned element using [firepath add-on of firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/), you will get multiple results. So, just confirming if there are infact, more of **"MDN:" textfields**. This will help in forming a better xpath to help you out.

Comment: i guess you dont understand what i mean. if i do that, it doesnt select only one input but multiples. for example,  if i select only user id tag then it also gets password tag as well. so it is not only selector.

Comment: @Vzwpowertestverizon123 - No it will not same css selector. it will have minor diff. please check.

Comment: Well, it will select multiple fileds if they are all can be found using that selector. In that case you can 1) use indexes e.g. driver.findElements(By.Css("you selector"))[0] to work with single element, 2) ask developers to add unique id for elements to simplify your job =) 3) if it's possible provide link to full html page

Comment: this is the full html link:view-source:https://marswebtdc.tdc.vzwcorp.com/cdl/lte/fdr_llc/fdr_search.jsp?3gOr4g=4g

Comment: the link is invalid. After navigating it shows only empty page with 'Page is unavailable' text. nothing more...

Comment: i looked at it, and even retyped text from screenshot (part with MDN text in <form>). And this selector (input[name='txtMsid']) works fine and selects single element. This form appears on the page or in separate dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate **"MDN: textfield"**(as referred to, in the previous comments), please try the below xpaths:

**1-** `//input[@name='txtMsid']`

This will locate the **input element with name attribute as 'txtMsid'**.

**2-**`//td[contains(text(),'MDN')]/following-sibling::td[1]/input`

This will locate the **input element under the td element, that is the first-sibling of the 'td' element, which contains innerHTML/text as 'MDN'**.

Comment: is it css selector? thanks for your help. but it still gets same error: unable to locate the element. driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//td[contains(text(),'MDN')]/following-sibling::td[1]/input")).sendKeys(strI);

Comment: full html link: view-source:https://marswebtdc.tdc.vzwcorp.com/cdl/lte/fdr_llc/fdr_search.jsp?3gOr4g=4g

Comment: both are xpaths. Assuming you want to send data in that textfield, please try using this code: **`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='txtMsid']")).sendKeys("your data to input");`**  -----OR------**`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'MDN')]/following-sibling::td[1]/input")).sendKeys("your data to input");`**

Comment: still gives same error: unable to locate the element

Comment: i added more html. please let me know